# Pass value of observable in component params

Tags: knockout.js

Passing an observable value as component parameters but component receiving observable.

```
<my-component params="uid: data.uid()"></my-component>
```

In component `params.uid` is observable not value.

Following shows *false*

```
<h3 data-bind="text: ko.isObservable(data.uid())"></h3>
```

Comment: show as the model containing the uid obsevable

Comment: Model is huge, so cannot post it here. From debugging I can see `params.uid` is observable and `params.uid()` outputs value not observable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [documentation states](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-custom-elements.html#passing-observable-expressions), if you pass an observable expression in the custom elements (components), then it will be automatically constructed as a `computed`.

> In general, with custom elements, if a parameter’s evaluation involves
>   evaluating an observable, then Knockout automatically constructs a
>   ko.computed value to give the expression’s result, and supplies that
>   to the component.

So, you need to unwrap `(ko.unwrap)` the `uid` in the component's model.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that `data.uid` is an observable containing another observable.
Something like

```
var a = ko.observable(1); 
data.uid=ko.observable(a);
```

You can try printing data.uid()() to check if that is so

```
console.log(data.uid()());
console.log(data.uid());
```

If the first one prints the value, and the second one the knockout observable function, you know that `data.uid` is an observable containing another observable.

Comment: I confirm there is one level of observable. I checked in Chrome debugging window `params.uid()` outputs the value and not observable.

Comment: Sorry typo in my earlier answer. Updated, can you check that.